# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::inRandonOrder()

Tags: php, function, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to fetch my related posts randomly. I read the docs, it says we need to use "inRandomOrder()" method. But when I tried it gives me this error.

Controller

```
related_categories_posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($post) {
         $categories = [];
          foreach ($post->categories as $key => $category) 
            {
            $categories[$key] = $category->category_name;
            }

          $query->where('category_name', $categories);
          })->where('id', '!=', $post->id)
            ->inRandonOrder()
            ->take(3)
            ->get();
  }
```

Any advice ?
                ->get();

Comment: `inRandonOrder` != `inRandomOrder`.

Comment: @tkausl ... I need to remove that question....